# C# - ExecuteNonQuery isn't executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, executenonquery

I am trying to run a stored procedure with parameters as shown below:

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPurchase]
     @commodityName VARCHAR(10),
     @startdate DATE,  
     @enddate DATE,
     @tonnes FLOAT,
     @lots INT,
     @value FLOAT,
     @ccy VARCHAR(3),
     @clientref VARCHAR(50),
     @clientid INT,
     @userid INT
AS
BEGIN
    ........
    ........
    ........
END
```

C# code to execute this stored procedure:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spPurchase", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@commodityName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ddlMetals.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endDate.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tonnes", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble(tbQuantity.Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lots", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Float).Value = DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ccy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@clientref", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "EigerTest";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@clientid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Utils.LoggedInUserId);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Utils.LoggedInUsersAccountId);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
}
finally
{
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

The stored procedure runs fine from SQL Server and the C# code is successfully connecting to the database. However, it is not executing the stored procedure and is not producing any exceptions or errors.

Looking at recent queries in my database, it looks as though my C# code may be just trying to CREATE the stored procedure rather than executing it.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the stored proc doing?

Comment: Just updating various tables.

Comment: `lots` is `float` in your code but `int` in db; `value` is `int` in your code but `float` in db; does it cause an issue?

Comment: Just open Sql profiler and see what happens.

Comment: When you say the SP is not executing and no errors, .Net is sending the parameters to SP but inside queries didn't do something; Did you try using `SQL Server Profiler`.  You can see the SP with the actual parameters passed to SQL Server.  Take that out of profiler and try to debug from SSMS

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your Catch block and see what happens. You might be missing the exception altogether.

Comment: Double-check your connection string and make sure you're pointing at the database you think you are?  I would think an error would surface if it was something like a parameter mismatch.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` isn't going to return any results, only the affected rows. Have you examined the number of rows affected? Also, can you post the sproc?

Comment: Have you tried enumerating the results of the SP, if there are any?

Comment: I don't have permissions to run a Profiler unfortunately. I know it is connecting to my database as I can see the code is trying to create the Stored Procedure. It's just not executing it. `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` returns 0 as well.

Comment: @Johnathan, how do you know that it is trying to create?

Comment: @techspider Because I have a query which I run to view recently run queries. Every time I click my c# button, I can see the query `CREATE PROCEDURE....`

Answer (score 0):

When debugging a similar issue, I found the problem was my stored procedure. It didn't raise any SQL errors by default. So I added a `RAISEERROR` statement, but even that didn't cause an issue. I had to change my `RAISEERROR` to use a severity of >10 before it would surface into C#.

After that it was straightforward to debug. There was a type mismatch in the parameters I passed in C# which caused an IF statement to fail in the procedure. Without the `RAISEERROR` it was really perplexing to debug.